# What is the correct terminology to describe what goes on in project.clj and core.clj?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

When explaining Clojure builds, I would like to use the correct terminology. Therefore my overarching question is, am I using the correct terminology in the following examples?

Given one of my project.clj files:

```
(defproject bene-csv "1.0.4-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "A csv parsing library"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "1.3.2"]
                 [util "1.0.2-SNAPSHOT"]]


  :aot [bene-csv.core]
  :omit-source true)
```

I believe the correct terminology is I am creating dependencies to Clojure 1.3.0, clojure-csv, and one my my modules, which is named util.

Is that correct?

Given the header of my core.clj

```
(ns bene-csv.core
  ^{:author "Charles M. Norton",
    :doc "bene-csv is a small library to parse a .csv file.
        Created on March 8, 2012"}
  (:require [clojure.string :as cstr])
  (:require [util.core :as utl])
  (:use clojure-csv.core))
```

am I including or referencing these modules, or should I be using different terminology?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project.clj you are defining the dependencies for specific packages (or projects) that will be required in classpath for you project to work.

In the core.clj you are referencing to the namespaces or importing the namespace vars depending on what you use (:use or :require)